# Error with tabset within a model, when opening the model it does not show me the tabset with marking

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- Modal Nuevo Trabajador -->
<div class="modal" id="modal_nuevo_trabajador" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Trabajador</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="tabset">
                    <!-- Tab 1 -->
                    <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab_datospersonales" aria-controls="datos_personales" checked>
                    <label for="tab_datospersonales">Datos Personales</label>
                    <!-- Tab 2 -->
                    <input type="radio" name "tabset" id="tab_datostrabajador" aria-controls="datos_trabajador">
                    <label for="tab_datostrabajador">Datos del Trabajador</label>

                    <div class="tab-panels">
                        <!-- datos_personales -->
                        <section id="datos_personales" class="tab-panel">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <!-- Tipo Documento y Codigo -->
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Tipo Documento</span>
                                        <select class="form-control custom-select" id="input_trabajador_tipo_documento" required>
                                            <option value="">seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="01">L.E / DNI</option>
                                            <option value="04">CARNET EXT.</option>
                                            <option value="06">RUC</option>
                                            <option value="07">PASAPORTE</option>
                                            <option value="11">P. NAC.</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Código</span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_trabajador_codigo" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Ingrese su Código Alternativo">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <!-- datos_Trabajador -->
                        <section id="datos_trabajador" class="tab-panel">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <!-- trabajador_tipo -->
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Tipo</span>
                                        <select class="form-control custom-select" id="input_trabajador_tipo" required>
                                            <option value="">seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="E">Empleado</option>
                                            <option value="O">Obrero</option>
                                            <option value="V">Vendedor</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhTP.png)

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfhTP.png)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28m8c.png)

```
It works in JS but I want it in html the checked:

 var tabDatospersonales = document.getElementById('tab_datospersonales');

// Mark the "Personal Data" tab as active
  tabDatospersonales.checked = true;
```

I'm experiencing difficulties when trying to set the checked property on elements of my interface, whether on a radio button or a tabset element within a modal. Even though I assign the checked property to indicate that an element should be checked by default, when opening the modal, it does not visually reflect that the element is selected.